# How to find services whose log on account is domain user in c++?

Tags: c++, service

Below is the code me using but it gives services whose log on account is LocalSystem too.
http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32CreateService.htm this link says that if SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS in EnumServicesStatusEx used, will enumerate services whose log on account will be of form "DomainName\Username". But this enumerates services running with LocalSystem account too.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

            PUCHAR pBuf=NULL;
            ULONG dwBufSize=0x00;
            ULONG dwBufNeed=0x00;
            ULONG dwNumberOfService=0x00;
            HANDLE hToken = NULL;
            LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS pInfo = NULL;
            LogonUser( L"administrator", L"local.com", L"Mypwd", LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken);
            ImpersonateLoggedOnUser( hToken );

            SC_HANDLE schService=NULL;
            SC_HANDLE hSCM = OpenSCManager( L"local-dc1", NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS );

            EnumServicesStatusEx(hSCM,SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO,SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,SERVICE_STATE_ALL,NULL,dwBufSize,&dwBufNeed,&dwNumberOfService,NULL,NULL);
            if(dwBufNeed<0x01)
            {
                printf("enum fail");

            } 
            dwBufSize = dwBufNeed + 0x10;
            pBuf  = (PUCHAR) malloc(dwBufSize);
            EnumServicesStatusEx(hSCM,SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO,SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,SERVICE_STATE_ALL,pBuf,dwBufSize,&dwBufNeed,&dwNumberOfService,NULL,NULL);
            pInfo = (LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS)pBuf;
            LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG lpsc; 

            DWORD dwBytesNeeded,cbBufSize, dwError;

            for (ULONG i=0;i<dwNumberOfService;i++)
            {

                schService = OpenService(hSCM,pInfo[i].lpServiceName,SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG); // need query config access 
                if (schService == NULL)
                { 
                    printf("OpenService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 
                    continue;
                }

                if( !QueryServiceConfig(schService,NULL,0,&dwBytesNeeded))
                {
                    dwError = GetLastError();
                    if( ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == dwError )
                    {
                        cbBufSize = dwBytesNeeded;
                        lpsc = (LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG) LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cbBufSize);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("QueryServiceConfig failed (%d)", dwError);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if(!QueryServiceConfig(schService,lpsc,cbBufSize,&dwBytesNeeded)) 
                {
                    printf("QueryServiceConfig failed (%d)", GetLastError());
                    continue;
                }
                wprintf_s(L"Display Name \t : %s \n", pInfo[i].lpDisplayName);
                _tprintf(TEXT("  Account: %s\n"), lpsc->lpServiceStartName);
            }
            printf("number of services: %d",dwNumberOfService);
            free(pBuf);
            RevertToSelf();
            CloseHandle(hToken);
            CloseServiceHandle(hSCM);
            CloseServiceHandle(schService);

       return 0;
}
```